# how to create an image url from a mysql database that only produces image names? (spring boot jpa RESTFULL API)

Tags: spring-boot, api, jpa, rest

I want to add the url at the beginning of the image data results in the form of an image name along with the image type, I have made it in the model section and added it in getImage but it can't and I can't try to setImage either, please help, here is my code:

**My Model/entity**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class ArticleDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    private String title;
    private String excerpt;
    private String content;
    private String image;
    private String publish_at;
    private boolean published;
    
    ArticleDetails(){}
    
    ArticleDetails(String title, String excerpt, String content, String image, String publish_at, boolean published){
        this.title = title;
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
        this.content = content;
        this.image = image;
        this.publish_at = publish_at;
        this.published = published;
    }
    
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "excerpt", nullable = false)
    public String getExcerpt() {
        return excerpt;
    }
    public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "image", nullable = false)
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "publish_at", nullable = false)
    public String getPublish_at() {
        return publish_at;
    }
    public void setPublish_at(String publish_at) {
        this.publish_at = publish_at;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "published", nullable = false)
    public boolean isPublished() {
        return published;
    }
    public void setPublished(boolean published) {
        this.published = published;
    }   
    
     @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Article {id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", excerpt=" + excerpt + ", content=" + content + 
                    ", image=" + image + ", publish_at=" + publish_at + ", published=" + published + "}";
        }
}
```

**My Repository**

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.lai.articlews.articlews.model.ArticleDetails;

@Repository
public interface ArticleDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<ArticleDetails,Long>{
    Optional <ArticleDetails> findById(Long id);
}
```

**My Controller**

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/articledetail", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public Optional<ArticleDetails> getDetailArticle(@RequestParam(name = "id") long id){
            return articleDetailRepository.findById(id);
 }
```

**i want to make json result from**

```
{
"image": "120_image.jpg",
....
}
```

**To This**

```
{
    "image": "localhost:8080/image/120_image.jpg",
    ....
 }
```